# Replace anything inside a HTML tag ID

Tags: html, xml-namespaces, xmlstarlet, xmllint, html-xml-utils

Have searched all over Stackoverflow and Google, and the closest answer:

`sed -i -e 's|<element id="lastupdate">\([0-9]\{0,\}\)</element>|<element id="lastupdate">'"$(date -d @${contents})"'</element>|g' /var/www/html/index.html`

works only when the tag's content is empty. If it is already changed, it can't be used anymore.

The idea is to change anything inside this tag id, and not only when it is empty.

Here's a good answer about reading anything inside a tag id, using awk: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13148004/5623661. But it works only for reading (with awk) and not for appending/replacing (using sed).

Another idea is to not only having a way to replace: but another to, alternatively, append into anything inside the given tag.

Is it possible to use a tool that works for HTML instead of one specific made for XML?
Have tried:

Input: `xmlstarlet ed --update '//element[@id="daipeg"]' --value 'new' index.html`

Output:

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>Status - Floflis</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="icon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
    <link rel="icon" href="icon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
  </head>
  <body><h1>Floflis Status</h1><ul><li><p>Is DAI pegged to USD? <b><element id="daipeg">No</element></b></p></li><li><p>DAI now worth <b><element id="daiusd"/> USD</b></p></li></ul><p>Last updated in <element id="lastupdate"/> (updates every 5 minutes).</p><a href="https://floflis.github.io/" target="_blank">Main site</a> | <a href="https://floflis.github.io/blog" target="_blank">Blog</a> | <a href="https://floflis.github.io/docs" target="_blank">Documentation</a> | <a href="./api.html">DEV</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Desired result: changing the "No" inside `<element id="daipeg">No</element>` to "new", directly into the index.html file.

Comment: Please take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `sed` is the wrong tool. Please [Don't Parse XML/HTML With Regex.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3776858). I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, xmllint ...).

Comment: @Cyrus: yes, but they are poorly documented in an intuitive way (html-xml-utils, HXPIPE, xmlstarlet, xmllint). For example, tried this in `xmlstarlet`: `xmlstarlet ed --update '//element[@id="daipeg"]' --value 'new' index.html` and it only returned the html contents inside an XML tag (and didn't changed the contents of the desired element by id. Also, these are for XML, not HTML.

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: Done; have updated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Responding to [xmlstarlet](/questions/tagged/xmlstarlet) tag, I used version 1.6.1.)

If you fix a namespace issue and add an `--inplace` option you're
there (replacing `element` value):

```sh
test "${bettersorrythansafe}" || cp file.xhtml file.xhtml.was
xmlstarlet ed --inplace -N X='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' \
    --update '//X:element[@id="daipeg"]' --value 'new' file.xhtml
```

Or, with short options and a shortcut for the default namespace:

```sh
xmlstarlet ed -L -u '//_:element[@id="daipeg"]' -v 'new' file.xhtml
```

Note that the `--inplace` option is mentioned in
[xmlstarlet.txt](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/xmlstarlet.txt)
but not in the [user's guide](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/).
For more on the `_` namespace shortcut see the user's guide
[ch. 5](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/ch05.html#idm47989546158480).

To append to the value, for example:

```sh
xmlstarlet ed -L -N X='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' \
    --var peg '//X:element[@id="daipeg"]' \
    --var res "$((3 * 7 * 2))" \
    -u '$peg' -x 'concat($peg," and then ",$res)' file.xhtml
```

Comment: And how to standardize it to any (*) other tag other than <element>?

Comment: Figured out. Simply replaced `element` to `*`.

Comment: Can it work without requiring the HTML to have `<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">`?

Comment: If the HTML is also XHTML and the file contains no namespace declarations then yes: omit the `-N` option and the `X:` references. If you're lucky you can use `xmlstarlet format -H -R file.html` to convert HTML to XML.